# In the Stopwatch there's slight movement/ UI shifting in the minutes and seconds even if their value don't change and the update in the milliseconds

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

in React a TimerDigits component that takes time in milliseconds as a prop

```
function TimerDigits(props:{time:number}) {
 
  const formatTime = (time : number) => {
    const minutes = Math.floor(time / 60000)
    const seconds = Math.floor((time % 60000) / 1000)
    const milliseconds = (time % 1000).toString().slice(0, 2)

    return `${minutes.toString().padStart(2, '0')}:${seconds.toString().padStart(2, '0')}.${milliseconds}`
  }

  return <Typography>{formatTime(time)}</Typography>
}
```

and there is slight movement or vibration happen in the minutes and seconds,

any suggestions for what causes that behavior

thanks in advance

Comment: What exactly do you mean by _slight movement or vibration_, is the UI shifting? I have had some "issues" with this and it was due to the fact that the numbers do not have equal widths, so when centered they tend to "move"

Comment: Yes it is UI shifting for the number  (jumping) 
do you mean to add a fixed size for any of them?

Comment: Either use a monospace font for those digits to begin with, or indeed wrap this into individual elements that can get the necessary width assigned.

Comment: Yes, you are right when I do both it is fixed... thank you